# Custom Post Type Archive template page not found

Tags: page-template, archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

This following code is custom post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_technology_posttype' );
function wpt_technology_posttype() {

  register_post_type( 'technology',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Technology Providers List' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Technology' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add Techonology Provider' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Technology' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Technology' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'Add New Technology' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Technology' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Technology' ),

        'not_found' => __( 'No News found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Technology found in trash' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' =>'true',
      'hierarchical'        => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title','thumbnail','editor', 'comments' ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'rewrite' => array("slug" => "techno_type"), // Permalinks format
      'menu_position' => 22,
     )
  );

  register_taxonomy('techno_type', 'technology', 
  array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Add New Technology', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => true));
}
```

I created the page name *archive-technology.php*. I wrote script but page not found. How to display post in archive page.I also used following code in the `functions.php`:

```
function custom_post_archive( $query ){
    if ( is_post_type_archive('technology') ) {
         include 'archive-technology.php';
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_post_archive');
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, did you flush the permalinks?

Comment: When I used this code. I was change permalinks, But could not find the solution. Where is my coding problem? can you give any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried "archive_template" ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/archive_template

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need to use the hook `pre_get_posts` on this. Remove that part from `functions.php`. Then just put the `archive-technology.php` in themes root directory. Then go to you ***Permalinks*** settings page and hit ***Save Changes*** button. WordPress will need to regenerate the `.htaccess` file to use new archive template.

Comment: Thank you... :)